# What is the name of this hardware connector?

Tags: screws, bolts, hardware, washer

I am looking for the name of the part below. It is a metal connector that has a vertical threaded shaft into which a bolt can be screwed. The base has holes around the shaft that allows the part to be bolted onto a flat surface. This connector allows a bolt to stick up at precisely 90 degrees from the flat surface. I tried searching for this part on McMaster-Carr, Lowes, Home Depot, but cannot find the name.

Alternatively, some other fastener that secures a bolt exactly 90 degrees to a surface would also be useful to know about.

Any suggestions or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

[image: part diagram]

Comment: It’s a form of t-nut.

Comment: what size of a bolt

Comment: what is the BOLT. for ?

Comment: ‘Brad hole t nut’, if you believe Lowes: https://www.lowes.com/pd/Hillman-1-4-in-Zinc-Plated-Standard-SAE-Brad-Hole-Tee-Nut/3012548

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said **Bolt** and not pipe, they look like this, Used in the ceiling and walls.

[image: bolt]

Source: https://www.ebay.com/itm/Stainless-Steel-Wall-Mount-Ceiling-Mount-Pipe-Supports-2-Pack-19mm-1-2-inch/164191464953

There is also a whole family of **bolt flanges**, depending on application.

Comment: Did you draw that picture? If not it is expected that your answer provide attribution to where / whom the picture came from. Please update your answer to comply with SE policies.

Comment: @MichaelKaras >>> Published the source.

Comment: Looks good to go!

Answer (score 2):

It is called a "floor flange".

These are typically used for threaded pipe- I have not seen ones that are made for bolts.

[image]

Comment: Also used in the tops or bottoms of speaker cabinets - (not particularly home use) - I use them to sit speaker upon speaker, rather like a threaded top hat. Thread (12mm) goes right through.